# Posting not working via JS (Jquery) but is with form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a rather confusing problem.

I have a php file (http://example.com/delete.php)

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$logged_in_user = $_SESSION['username'];
require_once('../classes/config.php');
require_once('../classes/post.php');
$post = new Post(NULL,$_POST['short']);
#print_r($post);
try {
 if ($post->user_id == $user_id) {
  $pdo = new PDOConfig();     

   $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=:id";

   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array(':id'=>$post->id));       

  $pdo = NULL;
 }
 else {throw new Exception('false');}
}       
catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'false';
}
?>
```

and I'm trying to get this jquery to post data to it, and thus delete the data.

```
$('.post_delete').bind('click', function(event) {

    var num = $(this).data('short');

    var conf = confirm("Delete This post? (" + num + ")");

    if (conf == true) {
        var invalid = false;
        $.post("http://example.com/delete.php", {short: num},
        function(data){

            if (data == 'false') {
                alert('Deleting Failed!');
                invalid = true;
            }
        });

        if (invalid == false) { 
          alert("post Has Been Deleted!");
        } 
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }


    } 
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }



});
```

and when I do that, it returns "Post Has Been Deleted!" but does not delete the post.

Confused by that, I made a form to test the php.

```
<form action="http://example.com/delete.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="8" name="short"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

which works beautifully. Very odd.

I have code almost identical for deleting of a comment, and that works great in the javascript.

Any ideas? Beats me.

Thanks in advance,
Will

EDIT:
this works... but doesn't follow the href at the end, which is the desired effect. Odd.

```
$('.post_delete').bind('click', function(event) {

    var num = $(this).data('short');

    var conf = confirm("Delete This Post? (http://lala.in/" + num + ")");

    if (conf == true) {
        var invalid = false;
        $.post("http://example.com/delete/post.php", {short: num},
        function(data){

            if (data == 'false') {
                alert('Deleting Failed!');
                invalid = true;
            }
        });

        if (invalid == false) { 
          alert("Post Has Been Deleted!");
        ******************************************
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        ******************************************
        } 
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }


    } 
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }



   });
```

Comment: So what's the difference between the normal js code and the form js code which works?

Comment: @Andy no, seems to be null or never returned. I did alert(data); nothing came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP script delete the post, it doesn't return anything.

---

My bad, it's not answering the real question, but still is a mistake ;)

Actually, it seems that PHP session and AJAX doesn't quite work well together sometimes.

It means that `if ($post->user_id == $user_id)` will never validate, hence the non-deleting problem.

2 ways to see this :

1. Log `$user_id` and see if it's not `null`
2. Try to send the `$_SESSION['user_id']` with your ajax post and check with it. But not in production, for security reason.

---

**1-**

Your PHP should return something in **every** case (at least, when you're looking for a bug like your actual case).

```
<?php
[...]
try {
 if ($post->user_id == $user_id) {
  [...]
  echo 'true';
 }
 else {throw new Exception('false');}
}       
catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'false';
}
?>
```

**2-**

jQuery is nice to use for AJAX for many reasons. For example, it handles many browsers and make checks for you but moreover, you can handle success and error in the same `.ajax()` / `.post()` / `.get()` function \o/

```
$('.post_delete').bind('click', function(event) {
    var num = $(this).data('short'); // If that's where your data is... Fair enough.
    if (confirm("Delete This Post? (http://lala.in/" + num + ")")) {
        $.post("delete/post.php", {short: num}, // Relative is nice :D
        function(data){
            if (data == 'false') {
                alert('Deleting Failed!');
             }else{
                alert("Post Has Been Deleted!");
                // Your redirection here ?
            }
        });
     }
});
```

**3-**

If you need to send data from a form to a script and then do a redirection, **I won't recommand AJAX which is usually use not to leave the page** ! 
Therefore, you should do what's in your comment, a form to a PHP script that will apparently delete something and then do a redirection.

Comment: granted, and the "Post Has Been Deleted!" was shown. However, the troubling part is it **was not** deleted. It was only deleted when I tried with the form.

Comment: If that was the case would it not return "false", and thus not pretend like it has been deleted?

Comment: @wills : that must come from the js as Nick said. But then, we can't say more than this until you can make some tests

Comment: I'm getting this in console: "failed to load resource: cancelled delete.php." Why might this happen?

Comment: I updated the javascript on the original post. I included the whole function.

Comment: @wills : In AJAX, you must use a relative path to the script.

Comment: really? Why does the other one work then? Hm, i'll try that out.

Comment: additionally, what should the permissions of a folder containing "delete.php" be?

Comment: once again updated. I found the culprit, but it's odd, still need some help.

Comment: @wills : 1- Can you be more precise on your returns ? _Doesn't work_ is not a good one ;) 2- You should consider @Nick Craver answer for your JS. He's like a Guru. Yours seems quite not good (why using the `invalid` variable ? You should put every event on return in your `.post()`. 3- You don't tell us what the culprit is. 4- What `href` are you talking about in your new edit? Don't see any in your js nor in your php.

Comment: it seems returning true stops the post dead in it's tracks. I think I will circumvent this problem all together by posting to php directly and re-routing.

Comment: choosing number 3. Thanks for you help along the way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I don't see `num` defined anywhere...and `invalid` isn't set when you think it is, so you're not passing that `8` value back and you're getting the wrong message, either you need this:

```
$.post("http://example.com/delete.php", {short: $("input[name=short]").val()},
```

Or easier, just [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the `<form>`, which works for any future input type elements as well:

```
$.post("http://example.com/delete.php", $("form").serialize(),
```

I'm not sure where your code is being called, if for example it was the `<form>` `.submit()` handler, it'd look like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $.post("http://example.com/delete.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    if (data == 'false') {
      alert('Deleting Failed!');
    } else {
      alert("Post Has Been Deleted!");
    }
});
```

Note that you need to check *inside* the callback, since `invalid` won't be set to `true` until the server comes back with data the way you currently have it, because it's an asynchronous call.

Comment: My mistake, num is defined and is a valid integer and is correct. It's just above the code provided

Comment: @wills - check out the updated answer...your `function(data) { }` runs later, while the `if`/`alert` *after* `$.post()` runs immediately, so `invalid` is not set correctly at the time you're checking it.

Comment: Interesting. Could be true and I'll fix that as soon as I get back to my computer. However, that won't fix the fact that it's not deleting id say. Additionally, the delete.php for commenting seems to with the if outside of the asynchronous call, which is odd. This is all in a onclick of an anchor, btw.

Comment: I assume data is null, which means invalid is still false. Anyway to error handle. I tried alert(data), nothing happens.

Comment: @wills - can you look in Firebug/chrome, etc, see what the actual response is?  Also, is your delete page on the same domain, protocol and port?

Comment: All yes. However, the firebug check will have to wait until the morning. I'll try that and a few other things and report back

Comment: "failed to load resource delete.php" cancelled. why might this happen?

Comment: I updated the javascript on the original post. I included the whole function.

Comment: once again updated. I found the culprit, but it's odd, still need some help.